# Broken layout in IE 9

Tags: html, css, gwt, layout, internet-explorer-9

I have a gwt application with various layoutpanels. My layout works fine with all browsers except IE9. The layout is completely broken. Text appears everywhere, images at the bottom of the page or just shown for a 3/4, etc. I have recompiled my app with the newest version of gwt 2.3 but it didn't change anything. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance. Here an image with the broken background:
[image]

Comment: try to validate your page on validator.w3.org, sometimes ie is less tolerant than other browser when it comes to incorrect html

Comment: Is IE9 loading the page in "IE9 mode"? Also, when you say "all browsers except IE9", does it include other IE versions? Is your page in "standards mode"?

Comment: The page doesn't load in standards mode. Yes in ie8 and 7 the app works perfect.

Comment: [The GWT 2.0 layout system is intended to work only in "standards mode"](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiPanels.html#Standards) - This means: Either use the GWT 2.0+ LayoutPanels (e.g DockLayoutPanel) with "standards mode", or use the old Panels (e.g. DockPanel) with "quirks mode". // You can get away with not following this rule sometimes, but especially with IE, it often doesn't work correctly.

Comment: Probably the the problem is that my panels in the screenshot are HorizontalPanels, and they don't work very well in standards mode. I tried the alternative given by google  by using a FlowPanel and  adding `float: auto` to its children but this doesn't really solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is very strange that in IE9 something is broken and NOT in the other browsers.

Try this:

-correct the issues for IE9 and your other target browsers
-then see if in the other browsers you continue seeing everything ok (probably you will have problems with IE6 and IE7 so then what I would do is to fix them with a hack)

So what I recommend is to beging working with the highest version of the browsers and THEN fix the older ones. Do the inverse way...=)

If this doesnt help you, could you attach us some code?

Answer (score 0):

A workaround to your problem might be to add the "X-UA-Compatible" meta tag to your HTML to tell IE to render in a different mode. For example, to tell IE9 to always render in IE8 mode:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
```

There are [many](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/beyonddoctype) [useful](http://farukat.es/journal/2009/05/245-ie8-and-the-x-ua-compatible-situation) [articles](http://acidmartin.wordpress.com/2009/03/21/using-the-ie8-x-ua-compatibility-meta-tag/) regarding this meta tag